# 1. A car starts from rest and accelerates uniformly over a time of 5.21 seconds for a distance of 110 m. Determine the acceleration of the car.

Tags: convergence-acceleration

A car starts from rest and accelerates uniformly over a time of 5.21 seconds for a distance of 110 m. Determine the acceleration of the car.

Comment: Use $s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$ with $s=110,u=0,t=5.21$.

Comment: Have you started from rest ? I mean, what have you tried on this issue ?

Comment: i am completely lost so I haven't begun.

Comment: a = (vf - vi) / (tf - ti)
a = (110m - 0m) / (5.21s - 0s) 
a = 110m / 5.21s
a = 21.11 m/s^2

this is how i would have answered it

Answer (score 1):

$s=\dfrac{a t^2}{2}$

$110=\dfrac{a 5.21^2}{2}$

$a=8.1ms^{-2}$

Comment: thank you! where does the two come from? the formula?

Comment: Uniformly accelerated motion.  Formula [2]  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Uniform_acceleration  where $r_0=0;\;v_0=0$ because the car starts from the rest